How to solve the method of Lagrange multipliers?
I understand how to formulate the equation for the method of Lagrange multipliers but don't know how to solve it.
This is a random example.
$$\text{maximize: }f(x,y)=x^3+x^2y-xy+y^2$$
$$\text{subject to: }g(x,y)=x^4-x^3y+xy+y^6=0$$
The formula for the Lagrange multiplier is as follows:

$L(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)$
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}(x, y)=3x^2+2xy-y+\lambda (4x^3-3x^2y+y)=0$
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}(x, y)=x^2-x+2y+\lambda (-x^3+x+6y^5)=0$
$g(x,y)=x^4-x^3y+xy+y^6=0$

I think this is hard to solve by hand, so I expect it to be solved by a numerical method. In any case, is there a way to solve it?
My interest is more in generalities than in this particular example.

hard is a true understatement.

You have three equations in three unknowns - in this case, they're all polynomials - so you solve it like you would any other. We can start by eliminating $\lambda$, for example:
$$\begin{eqnarray} 3x^2 + 2xy - x + \lambda(4x^3 - 3x^2 y + x) & = & 0 \\
\implies \lambda & = & \frac{-3x - 2y + 1}{4x^2 - 3x y + 1} \\
x^2 - x + 2y + \lambda (-x^3 + x + 6y^5) & = & 0 \\
x^2 - x + 2y + \frac{-3x - 2y + 1}{4x^2 - 3xy + 1}(-x^3 + x + 6y^5) & = & 0 \\
(x^2 - x + 2y)(4x^2 - 3xy + 1) + (3x + 2y - 1)(x^3 - x - 6y^5) & = & 0
\end{eqnarray}$$
If you expand this out, you get a polynomial of degree 6 in $x$ and $y$. The $g(x) = 0$ equation gives another polynomial equation in $x$ and $y$, so you can theoretically solve those simultaneously to find the intersection points. Wolfram Alpha suggests that there are two real solutions - one at $x = y = 0$ and one in the vicinity of $x = -0.2, y = 0.01$.
